# Error: 'currentUser' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I just updated Google Firebase Auth in Flutter app because I was getting some wried SDK errors but now I'm getting:

> Error: 'currentUser' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked.
> User currentFirebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

I looked at the migration guide and understand that currentUser() is now synchronous via the currentUser getter. but I'm not sure how I should change my code now to fix this.

```
static void getCurrentUserInfo() async{

User currentFirebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
String userid = currentFirebaseUser.uid;

DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users/$userid');
userRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){

  if(snapshot.value != null){

  }
});
```

}

Comment: If You want get user id actualy loget in try use some like this User currentFirebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.then(op => {
      const lk = op.uid;
    });

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to remove `await` and change `currentUser()` to `currentUser`.

So

```
User currentFirebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
```

Becomes

```
User currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

Source: [Verify email link and sign in](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#verifying-a-users-email)
Let me know if this works ^_^

Comment: Yep, it's working like charm, thx !!

Answer (score 0):

Its done like this :

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid = user.getUid();
```